# List of lists python: combine list elements that are the same size

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists in python:

```
[[1],[2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10,11],[12,13,14,15,16],[17]]
```

I would like to combine the sublists into a single sublist if they hold the same number of elements:

```
[[1,2,17],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]]
```

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `chain` from `itertools`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

lst = [[1],[2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10,11],[12,13,14,15,16],[17]]

result = [list(chain.from_iterable(v)) for k, v in groupby(sorted(lst, key=lambda h: len(h)), lambda x: len(x))]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 17], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

- `sorted(lst, key=lambda h: len(h))` to sort your list by len
- then use `groupby` to group your list by  `len` of list

Answer (score 1):

A "simpler" approach without `itertools`:

```
dictByLength = {}
for i in mylist:
    dictByLength[len(i)] = dictByLength.get(len(i), []) + i
print(list(dictByLength.values()))
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 17], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach (without using `itertools`):

```
l = [[1],[2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8,9,10,11],[12,13,14,15,16],[17]]

# create one sublist for each possible length
m = [[] for size in range(len(max(l, key=len)))]

# append to each size-sublist, the appropriate sublist
for sub_l in l:
    size = len(sub_l)
    m[size - 1] += sub_l

# remove empty sub lists
m = [sub_m for sub_m in m if sub_m]

print(m)

[[1, 2, 17], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]]
```